# Wordpress Bitnami on GCP - database error ip change

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitnami

Please help me out.

I installed WordPress Multi-Tier Certified by Bitnami and Automattic on google cloud platform to develop a website and when it's almost finished my vm instance restarted or something and it changed IP....

Now I cannot access it. It says: Error establishing a database connection. I tried to restart the servers for mysql and stuff but when I use these commands down below it says command not found:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
and
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

Please help me out to start my wordpress working again I really need to save everything that's there..

Comment: Do not panic, you have not lost anything. Bitnami's documentation is fairly good: https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress There are also Linux commands to find programs. Google search `find program`. You must read the documentation for the setup you installed. There are differences between their different setups.